# Is it possible to add a value into a list if it meets certain criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to make a code that shows you the position you are in after entering your score and name?

```
#name_score before input and execution 
name_score = [['Never', '69'], ['Gonna', '66'], ['Give', '65'], ['You', '64'], ['Up', '62'], ['Never', '60'], ['Gonna', '59'], ['Let', '55'], ['You', '54'], ['Down', '53']]

name = input('Enter your name: ')
score = int(input('Enter your score: '))

scores = []
for x in name_score:
    scores.append(x[1])

if score in range (int(scores[9]), int(scores[0])):
    name_score.append([name, score])

print(name_score)
```

The problem with my current code is I am unable to find the exact position the number can go into, thus when doing `.append()` I am only able to bring it to the back of the code. If I were to use index, they will give me a value error if my score is not in the list `e.g if my score is 67, they cant return me a position`.

Expected Result:

```
#program when it is executed *Example 1* 

Enter your name = Mark
Enter your score = 54
Congratulations! You are position 10 on the score board.
 

#name_score after user input
name_score =  [['Never', '69'], ['Gonna', '66'], ['Give', '65'], ['You', '64'], ['Up', '62'], ['Never', '60'], ['Gonna', '59'], ['Let', '55'], ['You', '54'], ['Mark', '54']]


#program when it is executed *Example 2* 

Enter your name = John
Enter your score = 68
Congratulations! You are position 2 on the score board.


#name_score after user input
name_score = [['Never', '69'], ['John', '67'], ['Gonna', '66'], ['Give', '65'], ['You', '64'], ['Up', '62'], ['Never', '60'], ['Gonna', '59'], ['Let', '55'], ['You', '54']]


#program when it is executed *Example 3*

Enter your name = Bob
Enter your score = 40
Sorry, you did not make it into the score board.


#name_score after user input
name_score = [['Never', '69'], ['Gonna', '66'], ['Give', '65'], ['You', '64'], ['Up', '62'], ['Never', '60'], ['Gonna', '59'], ['Let', '55'], ['You', '54'], ['Down', '53']]
```

Essentially the program will check your score with the scores in `name_score`, and if your score is `65`, you will end up in position 4, and the scores after that will have to shift down by 1, with `['Down', '53']` out of the score board.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please give it a try, post your attempt, and explain what did not work.

Comment: This is where i can do until, because I am stuck at the value error if I were to use `.index()`

Comment: Take a look at the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module, as an alternative to append.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are some tools in the standard library that are useful for similar problems, but I couldn't figure out how to make them work here:

- [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is basically a list with a limited length, but it won't let you insert if it's already full
- [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) lets you find the point in a sorted list where a new element should be inserted, but it doesn't seem to support a reverse-sorted list

So I wrote a function `place()` that finds where a score would go, then it's just a matter of `list.insert()` then `list.pop()` to remove the last item. If `place()` hits the end of the list without a match, it errors.

Sidenote: I don't know why you're storing the numbers as strings, so I made them ints for this example. I also shortened the example scoreboard for readability and made the items tuples since this is exactly what tuples are for.

```
scoreboard_example = [
    ('A', 69),
    ('B', 66),
    ('C', 65),
    ('D', 64),
    ('E', 62)]

def place(score, scoreboard):
    for i, (_name, existing) in enumerate(scoreboard):
        if existing < score:
            return i
    else:  # no break
        raise ValueError('did not place')

for test in ('Mark', 64), ('John', 68), ('Bob', 40):
    s = scoreboard_example.copy()
    try:
        position = place(test[1], s)
    except ValueError:
        print('Sorry, you did not make it into the score board.')
    else:
        print(f'Congratulations! You are position {position} on the score board.')
        s.insert(position, test)
        s.pop()
    print(s)
    print()
```

Output:

```
Congratulations! You are position 5 on the score board.
[('A', 69), ('B', 66), ('C', 65), ('D', 64), ('Mark', 64)]

Congratulations! You are position 2 on the score board.
[('A', 69), ('John', 68), ('B', 66), ('C', 65), ('D', 64)]

Sorry, you did not make it into the score board.
[('A', 69), ('B', 66), ('C', 65), ('D', 64), ('E', 62)]
```